# How to fit legend size to the figure?

Tags: legending

I like to fit the legend to the width of the figure because it is too wide. Is there any code I can add to resolve the issue?

```
Plot[{output1, output12, output2, output22, growth, growth2}, {t, 0, 
  10000},
 PlotRange -> All,
 AxesLabel -> {Time}, 
 PlotLegends -> 
  Placed[{"H sector's growth rate", 
    "H sector's growth rate with higher \
\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(\[Pi]\), \(H\)]\)(PLG)", 
    "L sector's growth rate", 
    "L sector's growth rate with higher \
\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(\[Pi]\), \(H\)]\)(PLG)", "Growth rate", 
    "Growth rate with higher \!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(\[Pi]\), \
\(H\)]\)(PLG)"}, Below],
 AxesStyle -> Black, 
 PlotStyle -> {{Red, Dotted}, {Red}, {Blue, Dotted}, {Blue}, {Black, 
    Dotted}, {Black}}]
```

[image]

Comment: I just updated the code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

Plot[{t, .8 t, .6 t, .4 t, .2 t, .05 t}, {t, 0, 10000},
 PlotRange -> All,
 AxesLabel -> {Time},
 PlotLegends -> Placed[
   LineLegend[{"H sector's growth rate", 
     "H sector's growth rate with higher \
\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(\[Pi]\), \(H\)]\)(PLG)", 
     "L sector's growth rate", 
     "L sector's growth rate with higher \
\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(\[Pi]\), \(H\)]\)(PLG)", "Growth rate", 
     "Growth rate with higher \!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(\[Pi]\), \
\(H\)]\)(PLG)"},
    LegendLayout -> {"Column", 2},
    LabelStyle -> 10],
   Below],
 AxesStyle -> Black,
 PlotStyle -> {{Red, Dotted}, {Red}, {Blue, Dotted}, {Blue}, {Black, 
    Dotted}, {Black}},
 ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image]

```
Plot[{t, .8 t, .6 t, .4 t, .2 t, .05 t}, {t, 0, 10000},
 PlotRange -> All,
 AxesLabel -> {Time},
 PlotLegends -> Placed[
   LineLegend[{"H sector's growth rate", 
     "H sector's growth rate with higher \
\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(\[Pi]\), \(H\)]\)(PLG)", 
     "L sector's growth rate", 
     "L sector's growth rate with higher \
\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(\[Pi]\), \(H\)]\)(PLG)", "Growth rate", 
     "Growth rate with higher \!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(\[Pi]\), \
\(H\)]\)(PLG)"},
    LegendLayout -> "Column",
    LabelStyle -> 10],
   Below],
 AxesStyle -> Black,
 PlotStyle -> {{Red, Dotted}, {Red}, {Blue, Dotted}, {Blue}, {Black, 
    Dotted}, {Black}},
 ImageSize -> Medium]
```

[image]